# Unity3D Change Project Name

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I just finished an Adnroid game made with Unity3D, but I cannot change the name of the project. 
I did rename the main folder, I deleted the .sln files, I opened Unity and chose Other Project, I also changed the name of the project in the player settings. 
I cannot find the name "New Unity Project" anywhere after all this but, if I install the apk to my phone, the name of the application still remains "New Unity Project".
What else can I do, where could this old name still be remaining? I could not find any other solutions.

I am using Unity3d 5.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you tried uninstall completely your app and reinstall after rename it or you are just trying to reinstall without remove it?

Because it could be android maintaining informations and using your old/first registered key informations instead of refresh them.

Comment: yes, I did completely reinstall it from my phone, and then did a fresh install of the app, still got the same name for the app.

Comment: Search for a AndroidManifest.xml file in your project and if it's there please try on remove (backup it, don't just delete) and test if now ProductName from PlayerSettings is working.

Comment: Thanks! that actually solved it. It gave me some problems with the Chartboost plugin, but I solved that with just adding this line


`<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />`

after this line

`<meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />`

in the manifest file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Try Edit -> Project Settings -> Player.